# Check if drive letter exists in batch, or else goto another piece of code

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a code that detects if a drive letter exists.

For example, to check if C: drive exists my code is:

```
@echo off
title If Exist Test

:main
CLS
echo.
echo press any key to see if drive C:\ exists
echo.
pause>nul
IF EXIST C:\ GOTO yes
ELSE GOTO no

:yes
cls
echo yes
pause>nul
exit

:no
cls
pause>nul
exit
```

But it doesn't work, it either goes to :yes if C: exists or shoes a blank screen if doesn't. What am I doing wrong, so that it won't go to :no?

Comment: Does it work if you remove ELSE?

Comment: The way your batch file is written, it is working correctly.  In the no part, after you clear the screen, you are not displaying anything like you are on the yes side, so you get a blank screen.  You can also take out the word ELSE to get to the no part too. Some of the answers provided also are very helpful.

Answer (score 25):

The main problem in your code is the `if ... else` syntax. The full command needs to be read/parsed as a single block of code. It does not mean that it should be written in a single line, but if it is not, the lines must include information to the parser so it knows the command continues on the next line

```dos
if exist c:\ ( echo exists ) else ( echo does not exist)

----

if exist c:\ (
    echo exists
) else echo does not exist

----

if exist c:\ ( echo exists
) else echo does not exist

----

if exist c:\ (
    echo exists
) else (
    echo does not exist
)
```

Any of the previous codes will work as intended.

Anyway, the checking for the root folder of the drive will generate a popup for some kind of drives (in my case it was the multi card reader). To avoid it, use instead the `vol` command and check for errorlevel

```dos
vol w: >nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo IT DOES NOT EXIST
) else (
    echo IT EXISTS
)
```

Comment: This answer is very helpful in better figuring out if a drive letter exists in a batch, but does not really point out to the OP what they did wrong in their code.

Comment: the errorlevel returned by vol x: does not distinguish between the very different situations of  "The system cannot find the path specified." and "Access is denied."

Answer (score 7):

```bat
@echo off
title If Exist Test

:main
CLS
echo.
echo press any key to see if drive C:\ exists
echo.
pause>nul
::NB: you need the brackets around the statement so that the file 
::knows that the GOTO is the only statement to run if the statement 
::evaluates to true, and the ELSE is separate to that.
IF EXIST C:\ (GOTO yes) ELSE (GOTO no)

::I added this to help you see where the code just runs on to the
::next line instead of obeying your goto statements
echo no man's land

:yes
::cls
echo yes
pause>nul
exit

:no
::cls
echo no
pause>nul
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

**Verified to work under Win7.**
Try with an (existing and non-existing) drive letter of your choice:

```
@IF EXIST O:\ (GOTO cont1)
@ECHO not existing
@GOTO end

:cont1
@ECHO existing!

:end
```

Comment: I can't see the difference to the two year old answers. But this answer has less informations.

Comment: It's simpler in terms of brackets and the literal to the OP's question (headline).

Answer (score 0):

Try by including '**echo no**'. Use this under ':no'

Answer (score 0):

hmmpf!

```
 C:\>net use
 
 Status       Local     Remote                    Network
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 OK           A:        \\ENTDC01\Accounting_LawCorp Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           B:        \\ENTDC01\Accounting_LLP     Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           G:        \\ENTDC01\GenShares          Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           I:        \\ENTDC01\ID                 Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           K:        \\entdc01\KO_Holdings        Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           L:        \\ENTDC01\Library            Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           P:        \\ENTDC01\PDrives\rokimaw    Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           Q:        \\ENTDC01\soluno             Microsoft Windows Network
 OK           S:        \\entdc01\Synergy Scans      Microsoft Windows Network
 The command completed successfully.

c:\>if exist g:\ ( echo yes) else (echo no)
no

c:\>if exist p:\ ( echo yes) else (echo no)
yes
```